# Trying to save an array of objects into UserDefaults

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

im trying to save an array of objects into userdafaults and I got error "Attempt to set a non-property-list object"

```
import UIKit

var defaults = UserDefaults()
class Item {
    var title: String = ""
    var done: Bool = false
}

var array = [Item]()


let newTitle = Item()
newTitle.title = "hey"
array.append(newTitle)
let newTitle2 = Item()
newTitle2.title = "hey"
array.append(newTitle2)
let newTitle3 = Item()
newTitle3.title = "hey"
array.append(newTitle3)
let newTitle4 = Item()
newTitle4.title = "hey"
array.append(newTitle4)


defaults.set(array, forKey: "arrays")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift the most reasonable way is to adopt `Codable` and save the array either as Property List or JSON

```
class Item : Codable {
    var title: String = ""
    var done: Bool = false
}

...

do {
   let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(array)
   // or let data = try PropertyListEncoder().encode(array)
   defaults.set(data, forKey: "arrays")
} catch { print(error) }
```